# Visual C++ Project type for Windows Service that calls the WinAPI directly

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-services

I want to create a Windows Service using the Windows API (no .NET, no ATL/COM). What kind of project do I have to create in Visual C++ 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Win32 Console Application" or "Win32 Project" - then deal with the service setup/control code yourself.

See [Writing a Service Program's main Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)